# Can Flask support an optional parameter in a POST request?

Tags: python, post, flask

In the application, the user has a choice to upload a picture or not. But

```
picture_url = request.files['image']
```

seems to cause the page to stop loading the request if no such file exists. Is there any way to make this optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using syntax that throws an exception if the key is not present. Use `.get()` instead:

```
picture_url = request.files.get('image')
```

This returns `None` if the key was not set, e.g. no `image` field is present in the POST.

You could also handle the `KeyError` exception:

```
try:
    picture_url = request.files['image']
except KeyError:
    # no picture uploaded, do something else perhaps
```

Comment: Just a quick question. This might seem stupid but what is the scope of the picture_url in the second example? Will it be available to the entire function? Considering without the try it is inside the function body

Comment: @UtsavShah: it'll be available *if no exception was thrown*, in the rest of the function. You'd have to bind it in the exception handler too, or set a default *before* the `try`. In this regard it is no different from binding a name in a `if` handler.